# Python Dataframe is not iterable and length of dataframe is 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import txt file data into a dataframe. This is the code I used to load the textiles data then join them together in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as 
n254_1=pd.read_csv('input_1.txt')
n254_2=pd.read_csv('input_2.txt')
daf=pd.DataFrame({'run1':[n254_1], 'run2':[n254_2]})
print("length of dataframe %i",len(daf))
print(daf)
```

The problem is that the resulting dataframe is not iterable. Morever, when I print the dataframe "daf", I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` already returns a DataFrame, so `daf` is a DataFrame of DataFrames.  I suspect this wasn't your intention.  Are you trying to put two DataFrames together into one somehow?  If so, what would you like the final result to look like?

Comment: ok. I am trying to join n254_1 and n254_2 into one dataframe. How can I do that? @Frodnar Thanks

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101/

Comment: check concat optionn to join df's verticaly or horisontaly